# Trying to test my first Firefox extension by running web-ext run on my terminal but my HTML isn't rendering

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, tabs

The goal of my app is to render a form asking for the user's date of birth and then to display an age counter and the current time every time the user opens a new tab, but aside from the background colour, nothing else from my HTML file is rendering.

When I test my application using the local path, my JS, CSS and HTML all render properly - for that reason, and I've compared my manifest.json to a lot of examples provided by Mozilla and there doesn't look to be much to it, so I think mine is fine.. My file structure is very basic, with everything being in the main director except for the CSS file which is in a CSS folder and icons in an icon folder.

When I run `web-ext run` on my terminal, the background of the new tab I open in firefox changes according to my CSS, so I know there is a response. For that reason, I think the issue might lie in some way that I've written my HTML.

I've really been banging my head against the wall for the last week trying to figure out if there's anything different that what I normally do, but I think it might come down to a rule about using script tags in HTML that I'm not familiar with. Can anyone give me a hint of where I've gone wrong?

Here's the HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Memento Mori - New Tab</title>

    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link href="css/newtab.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="newtab.js"></script>
  </head>
 
  <body>
    <div id="main" style="width: 100%"></div>

    <script>
      if (localStorage.length == 0) {
        document.title = "Set up Memento Mori";
        document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = 
        `<div class="container">
            <div class="title"><h3>Set up Memento Mori</h3></div>
            <form>
            <label for="birthDate">Enter your date of birth:</label>
            <input type="date" name="Birthdate"id="birthDate" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" pattern="(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))"></input>
            <button type="submit" id="button">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>`;
      } else {
        document.title = "Memento Mori";
        document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = 
        `<div class="container">
            <div class="title"><h3>Memento Mori</h3></div>
            <div id="memento-lg"></div>
            <div id="memento-sm"></div>
            <div id="clock""></div>
            <button type="submit" id="clearDob">Reset DoB</button>
        </div>`;
        renderTimers();
      }
    </script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="newtab.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try moving that inline `<script>` tag to a separete file (like `newtab.js`) since webextensions don't like inline and remote scripts without a special key in `manifest.json`. You can look [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_Security_Policy) for more information

Comment: @wilkoklak Thank you so much for pointing it out, I read up on the CSP and it makes sense that that is my issue. I removed the JS over to newtab.js and it did indeed solve my issue of my code silently failing, but now I've run into the issue of getting my functions to execute.

What I've done now is added an eventListener to wait for the page to load, at which point I will load the main function (the script you see in my HTML). At first, everything works as intended, but when I enter in a DOB and submbit, nothing happens - the date of birth isn't added to storage.

Comment: @wilkoklak the JS regarding dates is here, sorry about the formatting:

`if (localStorage.getItem("birthDate")) {
    birthDate = localStorage.getItem('birthDate');
} else {
    birthDate = new Date();
}

$("#button").click(function(){
    var dob = $("#birthDate").val();

    if (typeof dob !== null) {
    const birthdate = dob.split("-");
    var parsedDate = (birthdate[0]+"-"+birthdate[1]+"-"+birthdate[2]);
    console.log(parsedDate);
    birthDate = parsedDate;
    localStorage.setItem("birthDate", birthDate);
    } 
});`